# <video> HTML5 не воспроизводится в safari

Tags: html5, видео, safari

Вставил видео на сайт через . Включено автовоспроизведение, звук выкл. Везде работает кроме браузера Safari. Подскажите решение.

```
<video preload="metadata" muted="muted" autoplay loop>

            <source src="video/1080p_1.mp4" type='video/mp4; codecs="avc1.42E01E, mp4a.40.2"'>
            <source src="video/video.webm" type='video/webm; codecs="vp8, vorbis"'>
            <source src="video/video.ogv" type='video/ogg; codecs="theora, vorbis"'>

    </video>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Проблема решается добавлением атрибута playsinline.

```
<video preload="metadata" muted="muted" autoplay playsinline loop></video>
```

Answer (score 2):

Еще одно возможное решение для будущих поисковиков: (Если ваша проблема не проблема с миметикой.)

По какой-то причине видео не будут воспроизводиться на iPad, если я не установил флаг control = "true".

Пример: это работало для меня на iPhone, но не на iPad.

```
<video loop autoplay width='100%' height='100%' src='//some_video.mp4' type='video/mp4'></video>
```

И теперь это работает как на iPad, так и на iPhone:

```
<video loop autoplay controls="true" width='100%' height='100%' src='//some_video.mp4' type='video/mp4'></video>
```

Comment: Видео задумано как фоновое. Ставить controls совсем не хочется.. 
А наверное можно выставлять controls="true" только для safari?

Comment: controls="true" не хочется но для safari обезательно

Comment: @Григорий, вот и не надо задумывать фоновое видео.

Comment: Нужно добавить к video атрибут playsinline. Controls не обязательны.

Answer (score 0):

бывает еще не воспроизводится на safari из-за того что видео в MP4 не с кодеком H.264, переконвертировав его это исправляет проблему

"The MP4 container format with the H.264 video codec and the AAC audio codec is natively supported by desktop/mobile Internet Explorer, Safari and Chrome, but Chromium and Opera do not support the format. IE and Chrome also support the MP3 audio codec in the MP4 container, but Safari does not."